# Please tell me how to create a toggle out of an image?

Tags: image, toggle

I want multiple images in a window. When I click on a image I want toggle out showing some info. I want this on all my images.

Comment: Please add some more details like the technologies you are using etc. for getting suggestions and/or answer to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post the technologies you're using so I assume you are using jQuery and html:

Here is the html example:

```
<div>
  <img class="img" data-imgid="img1" src="https://i2.wp.com/beebom.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg?w=640&ssl=1" width="200px" />
  <br/>
  <text style="display:none;" id="img1">Image1 ......</text>
  <br/><br/>
  <img class="img" data-imgid="img2" src="http://www.111ideas.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/download-rose-image.jpg" width="200px" />
  <br/>
  <text style="display:none" id="img2" class="text" hide>Image2 </text>
  <br/><br/>
  <img class="img" data-imgid="img3" src="https://processing.org/tutorials/pixels/imgs/tint1.jpg" width="200px" />
  <br/>
  <text style="display:none" id="img3" class="text" hide>Finally Image3 :)</text>
</div>
```

​and here is the jQuery code which handle the toggling process.You need to use toggle method based on the id of any text tag in the html code inside onclick function to toggle it:

```
$(function () {
            $('.img').on('click', function () {
                var txtId = $(this).attr('data-imgid');
                $('#' + txtId).toggle();
            });                   
    });
```

You can see live demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/gtU56/342/